# Non-programmatically affect the returned value of std::thread::hardware_concurrency()

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, stl

I have a parallel c++ algorithm implemented using STL algorithms and the `std::execution::parallel_policy` policy.

Now, I would like to be able to benchmark how much performance varies as the number of concurrent threads available increase.

It seems that c++ doesn't offer any way to let the user limit the number of concurrent threads used, at least for now.

Still, I was wondering if this limitation can be somehow circumvented by "letting the program read" that a lower number of threads is available (for example, disabling some CPU cores or tuning this information through the OS somehow).

I am not an expert on this topic and I would really appreciate your help.
Thank you!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55941814/c17-how-to-control-number-of-threads-in-execution-policy and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47028495/how-do-the-c-stl-executionpolicy-algorithms-determine-how-many-parallel-thre . As of now, it looks like this is not possible (without an implementation-dependent solution) but it might in the future with executors. Anyway, if you care about performance, this model is clearly not the best. It is just good to speed up sequential code easily. But it is neither flexible nor efficient.

Comment: Does your own code use `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`? If so, then this could be a good case for [_dependency injection_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). If you would define some `Configuration` object with its own `hardware_concurrency` method, and if you had a "default" implementation that called `std::thread::hardware_concurrency`, then you could also "inject" a special [_mock_ `Configuration` object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_double) during testing which had a `hardware_concurrency` method that returned whatever number the test required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and thank you for all your answers.

As [@n. m. could be an AI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m-could-be-an-ai) and [Jérôme Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12939557/j%C3%A9r%C3%B4me-richard) mentioned, there is no guarantee `std::thread::hardware_concurrency` will be used by STL to decide the number of threads used.

[Solomon Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/801894/solomon-slow) suggests to use dependency injection to affect the result of `std::thread::hardware_concurrency`. Unfortunately, because of the previous reason, this wouldn't solve my problem anyway.

After some days of research I found [HPX](https://hpx.stellar-group.org/) to be my best choice, mainly for the following reasons:

1. It allows to set the number of threads used through the CLI `--hpx:threads = N` where N is the number of threads used.
2. The high-level API is very similar to what STL currently offers thus it's easy and fast to integrate in my codebase.

Thank you again, everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing promises you that `std::thread::hardware_concurrency` is ever called by parallel algorithms (and AFAICT it isn't at least in libstdc++). So changing it may or may not accomplish anything.

libstdc++ in fact heavily relies on Intel's TBB for its parallel execution. You will need to configure that instead. Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786408/number-of-threads-used-by-intel-tbb) will be helpful.

libc++ doesn't seem to implement execution policies at all.

I have no idea about the Microsoft's standard library.